# Disabling the Query Tooltip in SQL Server When Viewing An Execution Plan

Tags: sql, sql-server, lag, sql-execution-plan

With very long queries in SQL Server, sometimes the execution plan can get very involved and will require a scrolling through the query text and the execution plan.

Except in between the execution plan and the SQL there is a reiteration of the SQL in a single string and potential indexes. When you hover over either of these it will expand to show you the whole query or suggested index. Per the image below.

[image]

The text will never appear and will lock up SSMS. I don't see the benefit to the SQL being shown in a tool tip.

Is there a way to shut it off?

Answer (score 1):

A possible way around this is to grab the XML query plan.  You can then copy/paste the XML into [SQL Sentry's Plan Explorer](http://www.sqlsentry.com/products/plan-explorer/sql-server-query-view), a free download.  Plan Explorer has excellent query plan visualization.

To get the actual XML query plan:

- Run the query in SSMS with `Include Actual Execution Plan` turned on.  If you can right-click somewhere without triggering the popup, you can choose `Show Execution Plan XML...`.
- You can run the T-SQL command [`set statistics xml on`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176107.aspx).  It has to be the single statement in its batch (run it alone, or surround it with `go`.)  If you try this option, make sure you turn off SSMS's query plan options, they interfere with `set` execution plan settings.
- Run SQL Profiler and under the `Events Selection` tab check `Show all events`, then check `Performance -> Showplan XML`.
- You can read cached execution plans from a dynamic management (`sys.dm_`) view:

([last two options from Justin's nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7359705/50552))

```
select  UseCounts
,       Cacheobjtype
,       Objtype
,       TEXT
,       query_plan
from    sys.dm_exec_cached_plans 
cross apply   
        sys.dm_exec_sql_text(plan_handle)
cross apply   
        sys.dm_exec_query_plan(plan_handle)
```

Comment: I like this answer a lot because it is a great workaround, but I'm going to hold out for a bit hoping for a direct solution within SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an SSMS-integrated solution, [Supratimas](http://www.supratimas.com/addin/buy.html) is a an SSMS add-in that provides an improved query plan visualization.

There's a free ad-supported version as well as a paid add-free version.

Comment: I actually find that the local SSMS query plan viewer suffices, but that massive tooltip is a killer and pretty much crashes SSMS.

Comment: Sadly I doubt there's a way of fixing that issue, and it's unlikely that Microsoft will prioritise this. Have you tried the free add-in? If it works, it works!